Problem with creating embeddings and insert into Weaviate
I tried experimenting with vector databases by creating one and OpenAI’s text-embedding-ada-002 model to generate embeddings and store them in Weaviate. Here's my code:
import weaviate, openai, json
from OpenAI_Key import OpenAI_Key as OpenAI_Key
ROOT_DIR = "Example_Drive"

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = OpenAI_Key()

# Connect to Weaviate instance (adjust this URL if using cloud)
client = weaviate.connect_to_local()

# Upload from text files
with open(f"{ROOT_DIR}/Data/Sample_File.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_file: 
    documents = [{'content':item.replace("\t",": ")} for item in input_file.read().split("\n")]

# Function to create embeddings and insert into Weaviate
for doc in documents:
    # Generate embeddings using OpenAI
    embedding = openai.embeddings.create(input=doc["content"], model="text-embedding-ada-002").data[0].embedding

    # Add the document to Weaviate with its embedding
    client.data_object.create(data_object={"content": doc["content"],}, class_name="Document", vector=embedding) # Pass the embedding as the vector

print("Documents and embeddings inserted successfully!")
client.close()

But every time I run this, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'WeaviateClient' object has no attribute 'data_object'
What am I doing wrong?

You're mixing v3 and v4 syntax. I suggest sticking to v4 syntax:
After running client = weaviate.connect_to_local(), you need  instantiate a collection
Then, you can call the collection's data class to insert or insert_many or simply use the batch import feature.
